# Strange UITableView:numberOfRowsInSection behavior?

Tags: ios, uitableview

There is something weird happening with the cells of my tableview. I have two custom cells, the first being "HeaderCell", and the second is "MapCell".

The table has one section, and two rows (hence the two custom cells described above).

I have added some logging in the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method. Here is the total method:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell: UITableViewCell

    print("outside if conditional (before) - section \(indexPath.section), row \(indexPath.row)")

    if indexPath.row == 0 {

        print("inside summarycell - section \(indexPath.section), row \(indexPath.row)")

        let summaryCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! SummaryHeaderTableViewCell

        // cell configuration goes here.

        cell = summaryCell
    }
    else
    {
        let mapCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("MapCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! MapTableViewCell

        print("inside mapcell - section \(indexPath.section), row \(indexPath.row)")

        // cell configuration goes here.

        cell = mapCell
    }

    print("outside if (after) - section \(indexPath.section), row \(indexPath.row)")

    return cell
}
```

However, the logs prints the following to the console:

```
outside if conditional (before) - section 0, row 0
- inside summarycell - section 0, row 0
outside if (after) - section 0, row 0

outside if conditional (before) - section 0, row 1
- inside mapcell - section 0, row 1
outside if (after) - section 0, row 1

outside if conditional (before) - section 0, row 0
- inside summarycell - section 0, row 0
outside if (after) - section 0, row 0

outside if conditional (before) - section 0, row 1
- inside mapcell - section 0, row 1
outside if (after) - section 0, row 1
```

In other words, it prints everything twice. My `numberOfSectionsInTableView` returns 1 section, and the `numberOfRowsInSection` method returns 2 rows.

The app looks normal in the simulator, where it shows the two rows as it should:

[image]

Comment: What's wrong with it being called twice? It's possible you just have an extra reloadData or something, but that shouldn't cause any problems.

Comment: This is normal. The table view may ask its data source how many section and how many rows per section there are any number of times.

Comment: Are you using `UITableViewController` or a `UIViewController` with a `UITableView` inside it?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not a problem

Comment: @jtbandes You are correct. I am loading some data and reloading the table in a method called in `viewDidLoad` ***..facepalm..***

Comment: @LouFranco: so *make that an answer*. That's not a reason to close a question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's likely that you have an extra call to `reloadData` which is causing the table view to query its data source an extra time.

However, this shouldn't cause any problems. The data source methods are meant to provide info to the table view about your data — if you provide the same info twice, nothing's wrong with that.